# HTML + CSS - Zoom Image on Hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to zoom single image on hover, I have 20 images, two lines, 10 in one line. My current code zooms entire line, could you help me with correct this?

html file

```
<p class="image">
<img src="images/100.jpg" alt="100!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/99.jpg" alt="99!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/98.JPG" alt="98!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/97.jpg" alt="97!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/96.jpg" alt="96!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/95.jpg" alt="95!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/94.jpg" alt="94!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/93.jpg" alt="93!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/92.jpg" alt="92!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
<img src="images/91.jpg" alt="91!" width="90" height="125" border="0">
</p>
```

css file

```
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(2); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(2); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(2); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(2);
}
```

It works correct when I use `<p class...>` before each image but with this method I have each image in single line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the selector from:

```
.image:hover img
```

to

```
.image img:hover
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a0jnzs8c/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to zoom:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<br>
  
<div class="zoom"></div>

</body>
</html>
```